# How to read multiple custom objects from Firestore in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using [example from documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) (for Swift). Here is recommended way of reading multiple documents:

```swift
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```

And here is recommended way of reading custom object:

```swift
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    let result = Result {
        try document.flatMap {
            try $0.data(as: City.self)
        }
    }
    switch result {
    case .success(let city):
        if let city = city {
            print("City: \(city)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
    }
}
```

There is no example for reading multiple custom objects. This was my try based on the previous two examples:

```swift
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                for document in snapshotDocuments {        
                    let result = Result {
                        try document.flatMap { // error: Value of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no member 'flatMap'
                            try $0.data(as: City.self)
                        }
                    }
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let city):
                        if let city = city {
                            print("City: \(city)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the error (I've placed it's content in comment in code above) I'm assuming that classes of document objects are different while querying for single object or multiple, even though their usual use is the same. How should I change the code for loading multiple custom objects so that it would work?

Comment: This is a super good, well formed question. [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QueryDocumentSnapshot) (which is what is returned from getDocuments) is a subclass of DocumentSnapshot and should have all of the same functions. However, it doesn't appear to. It sure seems like a bug to me so I would file a bug report with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) and reference this SO question.

Comment: I did as you've recommended and filed a bug report. For now my workaround is removing the try document.flatMap block with try document.data(as: City.self), but I'm guessing that flatMap is there for a reason and lack of it could maybe cause an issue in some cases.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more correct information. The Firebase documentation on this topic is vague at best and doesn't really define what the use care of the Result object is. It looks like they are working on an update so it will be more clear going forward. Thanks for bringing attention to this as the documentation was confusing and needed clarification.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, getDocument returns a DocumentSnapshot which is a subset of DocumentSnapshot? which is optional so it can be used with a Results object .flatmap.

In the second example, getDocuments doesn't return a DocumentSnapshot, it returns a QueryDocumentSnapshot:

> QueryDocumentSnapshots guarantee that their contents are always
>   nonnull

So that means it is not an optional and cannot be used with .flatmap as it cannot be unwrapped.

The Firebase Documentation shows [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QueryDocumentSnapshot) is a subclass of DocumentSnapshot, DocumentSnapshot is optional, QueryDocumentSnapshot is not.

In this case, .flatmap is being used to unwrap a DocumentSnapshot (an optional) - whats happening is that the object within Result would be double wrapped optional without it. So .flatmap unwraps it once and then `if let city = city {` unwraps it again so it ends up being just the city object.

Here's what I would do... Replace that code with something like this

```
func getCities() {
    let docRef = db.collection("cities")
    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
            for document in snapshotDocuments {
                do {
                    if let city = try document.data(as: City.self) {
                        print(city.name)
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

I am going to borrow this from github because it makes the use of the Results (as shown in the documentation) much more clear.

```
There are thus three cases to handle, which Swift lets us describe
nicely with built-in sum types:

      Result
        /\
   Error  Optional<City>
               /\
            Nil  City //<- we get the actual city with `if let city = city {`
```

Comment: Actually getDocument returns a `DocumentSnapshot?` An optional is a valid input value for a `Result` type. If you already have a non-optional `DocumentSnapshot`, there is no reason to construct a `Result`.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien What are you suggesting? I said in the answer, *getDocument returns a DocumentSnapshot* so I am aware of that - the point being that DocumentSnapshot has a .flatmap function, whereas a QueryDocumentSnapshot doesn't appear to have one (for whatever reason). I am recommending to not use a Results object (as Firebase shows in their documentation) as it seems to be unnecessary. I don't think its a case of the DocumentSnapshot being non-optional - the fields it contains are optional as they may not exist (nil)

Comment: Neither DocumentSnapshot nor QueryDocumentSnapshot have a `flatmap` function.

Comment: Right, using `Result` type is unnecessary for a non-optional type. Swift is enforcing that with a confusing error message.

Comment: And `flatMap` works on Optionals - see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap - flatMap(_:)
Evaluates the given closure when this Optional instance is not nil, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.

Comment: Improved sample and docs coming at https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/pull/161/files

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks for the clarification and I do understand how the Result type works. I mis-spoke saying *a DocumentSnapshot function* - my meaning was that .flatmap was being *used* on that document snapshot `for document in snapshotDocuments .... try document.flatMap` but it cannot be used on a QueryDocumentSnapshot which loops back to the OP's question. So, can we address specifically we .flatmap cannot be used on a QueryDocumentSnapshot?

Comment: Hey Jay, QueryDocumentSnapshots guarantee that their contents are always nonnull, since they've been fetched from the server so they can be confirmed to exist. This is allowed in subclassing since `DocumentSnapshot` is a strict subset of `DocumentSnapshot?` expressed in ObjC as `DocumentSnapshot *_Nullable` vs `DocumentSnapshot *_Nonnull`. You can just remove the `flatMap` or the nil coalescing operator and your code should function correctly.

Comment: @MorganChen Brilliant. Thank you for that very clear explanation - it really helped!